# Plotting in matlab with cosine and sine

Tags: matlab

Considering a function f(x)=sin(x)+cos(4x)-0.3 am supposed to

Write a Matlab script file that plots f(x) for 0 ≤ x ≤ 2π.
I have tried

```
x = [0 : x: 2pi];
pi = 3.14;
y = sin(x);
g = cos(4x)-0.3;
plot(x, y, x, g);
```

Comment: Don't you mean `x = linspace(0, 2*pi)` or something? Also don't define `pi`. Also MATLAB doesn't do implicit multiplication between a scalar and a variable you need to use `4*x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
x = [0:0.01:2*pi];
fx = sin(x) + cos(4*x) - 0.3;
plot(x,fx);
```

On the first row where x-values are generated, you can adjust the middle term depending on how many points you want from the interval `(0,2pi)`.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

1) Before you write the line `x = [0 : x: 2pi];`, x is a constant that doesn't have any meaning, so the expression won't work. Additionally, you need to declare 2pi as 2*pi. To make this expression work, you'll need to define a spacing between points. You could pick a random constant like 0.01 in @ptev 's answer, or you could pick a certain number of points by using something like. `x = [0 : 2*pi/100 : 2*pi];`

2) `pi` is a constant in MATLAB- not only is it inadvisable to have a variable with the same name as a constant; you're actually making your code less accurate. Delete the line `pi = 3.14`. Since this is defined after you use it, if 'pi' wasn't an intrinsic variable, your code would fail.

3) Right now, your plot plots the two terms of the equation separately; you want to plot the sum of them. How do you think you could accomplish this?

You would benefit highly from reading one of the many [Introductions to MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/moler/intro.pdf) that are available; it seems like there are some basic programming ideas in here that could help.